# Como mostrar resultado entre 3 tabelas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-select

Tenho essas três tabelas;

```
    table_1
    |---------------------|
    |   ID1 |     name    |
    |---------------------|
    |   1   |  'xxxxx'    |
    |   2   |  'xxxxxx'   |
    |   3   |  'xxxxxxxx' |
    |   4   |  'xxxxxx'   |
    |   5   |  'xxxxxx'   |
    |---------------------|

    table_2
    |---------------------|
    |   ID2 |     date    |
    |---------------------|
    |   1   |     '1a'    |
    |   2   |     '2b'    |
    |   3   |     '3c'    |
    |---------------------|


    table_3
    |--------------------------------------|
    |   ID2_fk  |     valu    |   ID1_fk   |
    |--------------------------------------|
    |     1a    |  'value1'   |      1     |
    |     2b    |  'value2'   |      1     |
    |     3c    |  'value3'   |      3     |
    |--------------------------------------|
```

e eu preciso mostrar algo similar a isso:

```
Eu preciso de um select que mostra isso
|------------------------------------------------------|
|   ID1 |     name    |    1a    |    2b    |    3c    |
|------------------------------------------------------|
|   1   |  'xxxxx'    | 'value1' | 'value2' |          |
|   2   |  'xxxxxx'   |          |          |          |
|   3   |  'xxxxxxxx' |          |          | 'value3' |
|   4   |  'xxxxxx'   |          |          |          |
|   5   |  'xxxxxx'   |          |          |          |
|------------------------------------------------------|
```

Como faço? Lembrando que a table_2 varia.

Comment: Qual a relação entre as tabelas? Existe chaves estrangeiras entre elas?

Comment: O sufixo _fk no nome das colunas na table_3 indica suas chaves estrangeiras...

Comment: User um Inner Join apenas entre a tabela 1 e 3

Comment: O problema é que eu quero um select que mostre o numero de colunas de acordo com a quantidade de valores da tabela 2... não dá pra fazer isso com o inner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @table_1 table
(
   ID1 int,    
   name varchar(100)
)

insert into @table_1 values
(1   ,  'xxxxx'  )
,(2   ,  'xxxxxx'  )
,(3   ,  'xxxxxxxx' )
,(4   ,  'xxxxxx'  )
,(5   ,  'xxxxxx' )


declare @table_2 table
(
   ID1 int,    
   date varchar(100)
)

insert into @table_2 values
( 1  ,      '1a'    ),
( 2  ,      '2b'     ),
( 3 ,       '3c'     )


declare @table_3 table
(
   ID2_fk varchar(100),    
   value varchar(100),    
   ID1_fk int

)

insert into @table_3 values
('1a',      'value1'     ,    1   ),
('2b',      'value2'     ,    1    ), 
('3c',     'value3'     ,    3     )


SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT t1.*, t3.value, t3.ID2_fk
    FROM @table_1 t1
    left join @table_3 t3
    on t3.ID1_fk = t1.ID1
    ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
   MAX(value)
   FOR SourceTable.ID2_fk IN ([1a],[2b], [3c])
) AS PivotTable
order by ID1
```

Só um detalhe aqui você vai precisar especificar as colunas no FOR `SourceTable.ID2_fk IN ([1a],[2b], [3c])`, se for usar as colunas da `table_2` , vai precisar ler elas para joga dentro do IN([]) .

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.

Comment: você alterou corretamente o código?

Comment: Acredito que sim, a primeira tabela é uma fusão de varias com join, tem algum problema será?

Comment: Desde que esteja correto não, mas não tem como analisa sem ver o que você fez.